# ¿Cómo emular un StackPanel de WPF en Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera saber de qué forma puedo emular un `StackPanel` de WPF en Windows Forms

Comment: si te refieres a esto http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/images/stackPanel_panel.png yo solo los he utilizado en windows phone, pero creo que es lo que necesaitas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar un `FlowLayoutPanel` y cambiar estas propiedades

```
AutoScroll = True
FlowDirection = TopDown
WrapContents = False
```

Resultado:
[image: StackPanel]

Aqui hay un buen [articulo](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2008/12/12/an-easy-stack-layout-panel-for-winforms/) sobre el tema

Referencia de [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Si es correcto. muchas gracias